# Div Br Image Column 1px Misalignment

Tags: html, image

Only the very last image of the column misaligns by 1px when I code this way. I know 2 other ways to code to get the result without the misalignment, (using ul or using multiple div in a row without any br), but it's disappointing cuz this seemed even simpler to me. What's the reason this happens!?

```css
    div.a {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    ul.b {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="a">
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" />
    <br />
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" />
    <br />
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <ul class="b">
    <li><img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-2.png" alt="daniel wegner's conditions of human action" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-2.png" alt="daniel wegner's conditions of human action" /></li>
    </ul>
```

Example page (I included the ul column just for comparison): http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/zzzztest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in you `img` class

```
img {
    display: block; /*Add this*/
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;/*Add this*/
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I just noticed, it's unnecessary to even put the img in a div with this code. Is there still any usefulness to have imgages in divs (search engine implications, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the `<br />` at the end of the first 2 images, I solved it by putting a `<br />` at the end of the last image and it worked.

```css
    div.a {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    ul.b {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="a">
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" />
    <br />
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" />
    <br />
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" alt="free will determinism and indeterminism" /> <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <ul class="b">
    <li><img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-2.png" alt="daniel wegner's conditions of human action" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-2.png" alt="daniel wegner's conditions of human action" /></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: That ended up putting the entire ul below it 1px off, but it's okay, @Maddy 's solution worked. Also, I read ul li is not good for images anyway due to negative implications with search engines and visually impaired people.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution! You can just div each individual image.

```
<div>
<img src="link" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="link" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
<img src="link" alt="" />
</div>
```